# How to cast year, month, day to date?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have data something like this:

```
year (string)(Partitioned) | month (string)(Partitioned) | day (string)(Partitioned) | products
```

I want to cast year, month, day to only one date as date and the filter it with the following query:

```
SELECT year, month, day, products,
FROM X
WHERE date >= date('2020-05-01')
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cast(year || '-' || month || '-' || day as date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am getting the following error:  extraneous input 'day' expecting {'.', '[', 'as',

Answer (score 0):

Do you talk about SQL Server? Then the best string format to cast to date is 'YYYYMMDD'. So you could cast your date numbers to strings, concatenate them and cast the result to a string again, like this:

```
SELECT [year], [month], [day], products
FROM X
WHERE CAST (
    CAST([year] AS varchar) + 
    CAST([month] AS varchar) + 
    CAST([day] AS varchar) 
    AS date)  >= '20200501'
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3;
```

You can also use the DATEFROMPARTS function which looks better:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT [year], [month], [day], products
FROM X
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS ([year], [month], [day]) >= '20200501'
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3;
```

Otherwise you could convert it in a single number and compare it. This is my prefered solution:

```
SELECT [year], [month], [day], products
FROM X
WHERE [day] + 100*[month] + 10000*[year] >= 20200501
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I talk about the Athena.